# Passing props a on button click

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, mern

```js
 <Slider {...settings}>
        {this.state.featuredMovies.map(movie =>
        <div  className="" key={movie._id}>

           <Card inverse style={{padding: "10px", width: "90%"}}>
        <CardImg  src={`/files/${movie.thumbnail}`} alt="Card image cap" />
        <CardImgOverlay className="movie-list-overlay">
          <CardTitle>{movie.MovieName}</CardTitle>
          <CardText>{movie.Description}</CardText>
          <CardText>
            <small>
            <a href="watch">
                    <Button className="btn-fill btn-movie " color="primary" onClick={movie}>
                      Watch  
                    </Button></a></small>
          </CardText>
        </CardImgOverlay>
      </Card>
        </div>
        )}
      </Slider>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

i want to pass the movie props on button click to the watch component so the watch component

```js
class WatchMovies extends React.Component {



  ComponentDidMount(){
    const { player } = this.refs.player.getState();
    
  }
  handleDelete = e => {
    console.log(this.refs.player.play())
  }
  handleD = e => {
    const {player} = this.refs.player.getState()
    console.log(player.currentTime)
    console.log(this)
  }

  

  render() {

    return (
      <>
        <div className="container-fluid bg-black">
          

          <div className="col-md-12 mx-auto pt-5">
          <Row className="" >
            <div className="col-md-12 mx-auto py-5">
              <Player
                  ref="player"
                  width="80%"
                  playsInline
                  poster="/assets/bg5.jpg"
                  src="https://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer_hd.mp4"
                  position="center"
                  LoadingSpinner
                  onEnded={() => console.log("ended")}
              />
              <Button onClick={this.handleDelete}>D </Button>
              <Button onClick={this.handleD}>D </Button>
            </div>
          </Row>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

i want to pass the movie props on button click to the watch component so the watch component. Watch component is where you will be redirect to watch the movie you selected from the movielist component above

Comment: How is your Watch component look like? Where do you call watch component in your code? Please share relevant code

Comment: Watch component is where you will be redirect to watch the movie you selected from the movielist component above

Answer (score 0):

Your `onClick` needs to be a function

```
<Button onClick={() => this.doSomething(movie)} />
```

Then you can access the movie value in that function

```
const doSomething = (movie) => {
  //Do some stuff with the movie
}
```